# CAS 6.2.0-RC1 cannot authenticate LDAP users

Tags: cas, openldap

I am configuring CAS 6.2.0-RC1 with LDAP on the same machine Ubuntu 18.04

All authentication tests fail, i noticed after launching Wireshark that CAS sends to LDAP the SHA-1

hash of the password and when comparing LDAP returns False response.

When i display the LDAP entries i've found that effectively  the password hash does not match.

Here is my cas.properties configuration and the displayed authentication error.

cas.properties:

```
cas.server.name=https://127.0.0.1:8443
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas

logging.config: file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml

cas.authn.accept.users=
cas.authn.ldap[0].type=AUTHENTICATED
cas.authn.ldap[0].ldapUrl=ldap://127.0.0.1:389
cas.authn.ldap[0].useSsl=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].subtreeSearch=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].baseDn=ou=groups,dc=localhost,dc=slapd
cas.authn.ldap[0].searchFilter=uid={user}
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindDn=cn=admin,dc=localhost,dc=slapd
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindCredential=1234

cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributePassword=userPassword
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeList=cn,uid,givenName
```

Error:

```
2020-01-13 02:45:21,729 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports [UsernamePasswordCredential(username=user, source=null, customFields={})] of type [UsernamePasswordCredential]. Examine the configuration to ensure a method of authentication is defined and analyze CAS logs at DEBUG level to trace the authentication event.>
```

Comment: You haven't provided properties file and displayed error.

Comment: Is the hash in LDAP SHA1?  Or something else?  In my case I was working with a legacy LDAP system that still used MD5.  I had to override CAS code because the algorithm does not appear to be configurable (in 6.1).  Next step is to figure out how to update hash on the fly to avoid forcing everyone to reset password...